# Deploy encrypted EAR file in wildfly

Tags: java, ear, ejb-3.1, wildfly-21

I am new bee with wildfly and deployment. I have a small application running inside wildfly container. I have a requirement to deploy it in hash. I am using Wildfly final version 21. I have exported an EAR file from eclipse. What I have done is that placed an EAR file in standalone/deplyments folder. I have also changed my standalone-full.xml by putting deployments tag under server tag

```
<deployments>
        <deployment name="EjbEAR.ear" runtime-name="EjbEAR.ear">
            <content sha1="Hex Hash will be here"/>
        </deployment>
</deployments>
```

The problem is that when I run the server, I get an error that create dodeploy file first and then server stops. Can anyone tell me that what I am doing wrong here?

[image]